# how to fix ipython notebook 0.12 dashboard links

Tags: 12.04, python

I've installed ipython 0.12 on a freshly installed machine with ubuntu 12.04 (precise), mainly because I wanted to use the notebook interface. Now it turns out that all the links in the python dashboard are broken. If I click on them, I get a url that looks like:

```
localhost:8089/Undefined<some code, e.g. 3435glk4w5lk4m5>.
```

If I remove the word "undefined" from the URL, I *can* open the files and edit them, but how do I fix this issue?

regards,

Dirk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully the fix will be in a 0.12.1 update before long. In the meantime, this is the change you need to make to get it to work:

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/commit/cb7ff561f33acff72035da212c70def49fd65437